# How do I run an apk on J2ME?

Tags: java, android

Whats up! I just want to ask, but how do I run an .apk file j2me. I know that this question HAS been asked, but I can't seem to find an answer. Also, i'm not asking to run j2me apps on android; there are already tons of emulators. Im asking for apks running on j2me. I also know that they are developed in different VMs. So, is there any way to do that? Also, another side note, how do i resize the screen of an apk file? Thanks!

```
                               -Apersonwithalaptop22
```

(Edited to be easier to be understood)

Comment: So, does that mean you CANT run apks on a j2me?

Comment: I don't think you understand the complexity of what is involved in an mobile OS. J2ME designed in the late 90's/early '00s has no Google services (maps, firebase cloud messaging), no modern graphics (OpenGL ES 2.x+), no sensors (accelerometer, compass, gyroscope), no modern networking (WiFi, SSL) and had a memory space in the single digit megabytes while Android Go (low end Android) requires 500 to 2000 megabytes. Just saying they both run a Java based language doesn't mean other Android required APIs block even a by-hand port of an App to such a legacy device.

Comment: Okay but can you please answer? Can you run it, even if it takes ages? And if so, how? Also, Im an ameatur programmer so I havent tinkered with these kind of stuff.

Comment: If you learn about CompSci you'll encounter [Turning Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) and more specifically Turning equivalence which implies given enough memory computer A can simulate computer B. You see this in emulators. The practical limit is usually physical memory so that the host J2ME system needs multiple amounts of original Android OS memory/storage to run, the other problem is how fast you can 'emulate' those instructions, if it take 10 to 1000 times slower then it isn't usable. So theoretically possible but in real practice not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, how do i make it turning complete? I've used a converteer to turn apk to jar (there is a converter for that if anyone's intrested) but when I bluetoothed it to my phone (Samsung GT Chat ET 2222) It would register it as an app but it would say it's uncompantible. So how?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  A J2ME environment wouldn't have the Android framework.  You'd need to write a complete android framework in the j2me language.  It's not as simple as just converting dalvik bytecode to jvm bytecode-  it's actually providing every single android class in the SDK.  It could be done, but it would take one person a few years to do, and some things would never work quite right.  Possibly you can find a project that's tried to start that effort, although I would doubt it-  android moves relatively rapidly for them to keep up, and j2me is basically dead.

As for resizing the screen of an APK file-  you don't.  APK files don't have a screen size.  Instead the idea is to write a UI that scales.

Comment: "j2me is basically dead" - that goes into the middle of Dukes heart.